# Last seen on WhatsApp?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, whatsapp-messenger

***"last seen"*** does it  mean that the person opened MY chat window with him, saw the conversation we had and then went offline?

or "last seen" only means that the person was using WhatsApp and not particularly my chat window with them ?

Answer (score 2):

**[What does last seen and online mean exactly?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848)**

> Online and last seen ***tell you if your contacts are online, or the
>   last time they were using WhatsApp***.
>
> online means that contact has WhatsApp open and is connected to the
>   internet. However, it does not necessarily mean they have read your
>   chat. last seen refers to the last time the contact used WhatsApp.